# About the new feature of wolframscript in version11.1

Tags: scripting

The verion 11.1 is available now,so the page of [Mathematica Quick Revision History](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) have summarize its upgrade.But the second last item is

> Self-executing Wolfram Language scripts extended to Windows

What's meaning of this item.Can anybody give me a example for this feature?I desire to know the new usage of script in *Mathemtica*.

Comment: I'm gonna guess it has to do with this line in [the WolframScript tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html#3525232): "To make the script executable, you need to set executable permissions. After that, the script can be run simply by typing its name at a shell prompt." I guess they've extended this past Unix now.

Comment: @MB1965 I will give a try after for a while. :)